# Flutter Firebase: Should I use a server to send my users notifications?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to send my users notifications on a ToDo app that I made using Firebase Cloud Messaging. The idea is that users will store entries in Firestore that have a `time` field of when that entry is scheduled. At this time I want the user to get a notification.

During this time, I was wondering. Should I be running this code on a server or on the users devices? I am working on the users' device side so far but I imagine if I have a server, the server can check all users and see which ones have entries that need to be sent at a certain time.

So, should I make a server or can I use Firebase Cloud Messaging just on the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) for this use case.

> Cloud Functions for Firebase is a serverless framework that lets you
> automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by
> Firebase features and HTTPS requests.
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions